# What is this equation with zeta from a T-Shirt in a video?

Tags: integration

There's an equation on a T-shirt in the [music video by Remy Zero for "Gramarye"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=NEEJecwFG0w#t=209).  There's not a completely clear shot of it, but it's something along the lines of:

$$?^{???}(z) = \frac{n !}{2 \pi ?} \int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}} d\zeta \,$$

Can anyone fill in the blanks and identify what that is?  Searched around a bit on line integrals and zeta functions and didn't find anything

[image: Gramarye T-shirt]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula. Not Riemann zeta at all

Comment: It's $f^{(n)}(z)$. See Cauchy's generalized integral formula. Now I really want that shirt.

Comment: That's not a zeta function.  Zeta there is just a dummy variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning comment into an answer.

That is Cauchy's integral formula. The full formula is given by

$$f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{n !}{2 \pi i} \int_{C}\! \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}} \mathrm{d}\zeta $$

Comment: Is it so worthy to be on a t-shirt?

Comment: @Sid It doesn't take much to [make it onto a shirt](http://www.snorgtees.com/sex-equation) in the first place... so I'd imagine it's as good as anything.  :-)